# Rails what does this line of code doing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can anybody can explain me this line of code

```
<% child_nodes = node.is_a?(Department) ? node.offices.where(parent_office_id: nil) : node.branch_offices %>
```

I am got confused by ? :
what this is called  ? :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this statement contains a ternary operator: `child_nodes = node.is_a?(Department) ?`

If it evaluates to true the first condition is executed i.e.: `node.offices.where(parent_office_id: nil)`

Otherwise this code is ran: `node.branch_offices`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

It's called ternary operator, which has form `condition ? if_true : if_false`

You could write it using `if` and `else`.

```
<% 
   if node.is_a?(Department)
     child_nodes = node.offices.where(parent_office_id: nil)
   else
     child_nodes = node.branch_offices
   end 
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a ternary operator. Another way to write this would be:

```
<%
  if node.is_a?(Department)
    child_nodes = node.offices.where(parent_office_id: nil)
  else
    child_nodes = node.branch_offices
  end
%>
```